# VBA Enter Business days?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a code for a template.  Every month I want the code to enter the business day.  However, when I try the code it does updates the business days but not on the spread sheet that I want.  It will update the dates on the person excel file.  Please advise.

```
Sub MG09Nov02
Dim mDay        As Integer
Dim Col         As Integer
Dim Dt          As Integer
Dim mMax        As Integer
Dim wNam        As String
Dim c           As Long
Range("B:C").ClearContents
Select Case Month(Now)
Case 2: mMax = IIf(Year(Now) Mod 4 = 0, 29, 28)
Case 4, 6, 9, 11: mMax = 30
Case Else: mMax = 31
End Select
c = 2
For mDay = 1 To 31
wNam = WeekdayName(Weekday(DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), mDay)), True,
1)
If Not wNam = "Sat" And Not wNam = "Sun" Then
    c = c + 1
    Cells(c, 2) = WeekdayName(Weekday(DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), 
mDay)), True, 1)
    Cells(c, 3) = (DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), mDay))
End If
If mDay = mMax Then Exit For
Next mDay
End Sub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify which two spreadsheets are involved, and which of them the code is running in. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you haven't actually disclosed the name of the worksheet that the code is intended to list the business days on.

```
Sub MG09Nov02()
    Dim mDay        As Integer
    Dim mMax        As Integer
    Dim c           As Long

    With Worksheets("BDAYS")  '<~~ set this worksheet reference properly!
        .Range("B:C").ClearContents

        mMax = Day(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 1, 0))
        c = 2

        For mDay = 1 To mMax
            If Weekday(DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), mDay), vbMonday) < 6 Then
                c = c + 1
                .Cells(c, 3) = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), mDay)
                .Cells(c, 2) = Format(.Cells(c, 3), "ddd")
            End If
        Next mDay
    End With

End Sub
```

Another method you might want to explore is to have the actual dates in column B, formatted as *ddd* to produce *Mon, Tue, Wed, etc*. while still retaining their full date value.

Comment: Thank you! It wont work "Object does not support the property or method. I have deleted the temp files.  Please advise